# Angular 2 Final Release Protractor Issue using Webpack

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, protractor, end-to-end

Today I was updating an Angular RC 6 application to the newly released final release version. Everything's working fine, however I'm having an issue with Protractor. I'm getting the following error:

`server.listen(port, opt_host, function() {`

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'listen' of undefined`

All I've changed from the previous version of the application is the `package.json` file. I'm guessing that this is a configuration issue but I can't seem to find anything that's changed with regards to the Protractor config.

Also I'm using webpack in this application - I don't know if it's an issue related to webpack. Maybe someone's had some issues with webpack and Angular 2 Final release version.

**protractor.conf.js**

```
'use strict';

require('ts-node/register');

require('core-js/es6');
require('reflect-metadata');
require("zone.js/dist/zone-node");

var helpers = require('./helpers');

exports.config = {
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/yii/application/test_backend_mvc/branches/INT-81_RD/ng-app/dist/',

  // use `npm run e2e`
  specs: [
    helpers.root('src/**/**.e2e.ts'),
    helpers.root('src/**/*.e2e.ts')
  ],
  exclude: [],

  framework: 'jasmine2',

  allScriptsTimeout: 110000,

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showTiming: true,
    showColors: true,
    isVerbose: false,
    includeStackTrace: false,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 400000
  },
  directConnect: true,

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
      'args': ['show-fps-counter=true']
    }
  },

  onPrepare: function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  },

  /**
   * Angular 2 configuration
   *
   * useAllAngular2AppRoots: tells Protractor to wait for any angular2 apps on the page instead of just the one matching
   * `rootEl`
   */
  useAllAngular2AppRoots: true
};
```

**npm-debug.log**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'protractor' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.3
3 info using node@v6.5.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'preprotractor', 'protractor', 'postprotractor' ]
5 info lifecycle test-ui-prototype@1.0.0~preprotractor: test-ui-prototype@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle test-ui-prototype@1.0.0~preprotractor: no script for preprotractor, continuing
7 info lifecycle test-ui-prototype@1.0.0~protractor: test-ui-prototype@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle test-ui-prototype@1.0.0~protractor: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle test-ui-prototype@1.0.0~protractor: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;c:\xampp\htdocs\yii\application\test_backend_mvc\branches\INT-81_RD\ng-app\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\daniel.grima\AppData\Roaming\npm
10 verbose lifecycle test-ui-prototype@1.0.0~protractor: CWD: c:\xampp\htdocs\yii\application\test_backend_mvc\branches\INT-81_RD\ng-app
11 silly lifecycle test-ui-prototype@1.0.0~protractor: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'protractor' ]
12 silly lifecycle test-ui-prototype@1.0.0~protractor: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle test-ui-prototype@1.0.0~protractor: Failed to exec protractor script
14 verbose stack Error: test-ui-prototype@1.0.0 protractor: `protractor`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:242:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid test-ui-prototype@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd c:\xampp\htdocs\yii\application\test_backend_mvc\branches\INT-81_RD\ng-app
17 error Windows_NT 10.0.10586
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "protractor"
19 error node v6.5.0
20 error npm  v3.10.3
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error test-ui-prototype@1.0.0 protractor: `protractor`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the test-ui-prototype@1.0.0 protractor script 'protractor'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the test-ui-prototype package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     protractor
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs test-ui-prototype
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls test-ui-prototype
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test-ui-prototype",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --profile --bail --port 8581",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "build:dev": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --bail",
    "build:prod": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",

    "test": "gulp test",
    "watch": "gulp tdd",

    "test:karma": "karma start",
    "watch:karma": "npm run test:karma -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",

    "e2e": "npm run protractor",
      "e2e:live": "npm run e2e -- --elementExplorer",

    "lint": "gulp tslint",
    "tslint": "tslint -c tslint.json src/**/*.ts",
    "protractor": "protractor",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update -- --standalone",
    "ci": "npm run lint && npm test && npm run e2e",
    "webdriver-manager": "webdriver-manager",
    "webdriver:update": "npm run webdriver-manager update",
    "webdriver:start": "npm run webdriver-manager start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common":  "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core":  "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http":  "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router":  "3.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0",

    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.1.16",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "ng2-cookies": "^0.1.9",
    "ts-node": "^0.9.3",
    "primeng": "1.0.0-beta.15",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-promise": "^0.3.0",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.22",
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-tslint": "^5.0.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.22.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-html-reporter": "^0.2.7",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "protractor": "^3.2.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.1",
    "tslint": "^3.10.2",
    "tslint-loader": "^2.1.4",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.3.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.0"
  }
}
```

**Update - Further testing**

For testing purposes I've created a new project using `angular-cli` with Webpack. I've done this to verify whether there's anything amiss with the configurations in my application. I didn't notice anything extraordinarily different. The only thing I've tried is updating `protractor` to the latest version `4.0.5`. Unfortunately I'm getting the same result: `Cannot read property 'listen' of undefined`

```
> test-ui-prototype@1.0.0 protractor c:\xampp\htdocs\yii\application\test_backend_mvc\branches\INT-81_RD\ng-app                                                                                     
> protractor                                                                                                                                                                                        

[16:41:24] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...                                                                                                                                                
[16:41:24] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver                                                                                                                                            
[16:41:24] E/launcher - Cannot read property 'listen' of undefined                                                                                                                                  
[16:41:24] E/launcher - TypeError: Cannot read property 'listen' of undefined                                                                                                                       
    at isFree (c:\xampp\htdocs\yii\application\test_backend_mvc\branches\INT-81_RD\ng-app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\net\portprober.js:171:9)                                                  
    at findPort (c:\xampp\htdocs\yii\application\test_backend_mvc\branches\INT-81_RD\ng-app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\net\portprober.js:203:7)                                                
    at c:\xampp\htdocs\yii\application\test_backend_mvc\branches\INT-81_RD\ng-app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\net\portprober.js:192:5                                                           
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (c:\xampp\htdocs\yii\application\test_backend_mvc\branches\INT-81_RD\ng-app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1379:14)                           
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (c:\xampp\htdocs\yii\application\test_backend_mvc\branches\INT-81_RD\ng-app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2913:14)                                       
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (c:\xampp\htdocs\yii\application\test_backend_mvc\branches\INT-81_RD\ng-app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2896:21)                                   
    at asyncRun (c:\xampp\htdocs\yii\application\test_backend_mvc\branches\INT-81_RD\ng-app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2775:27)                                                 
    at c:\xampp\htdocs\yii\application\test_backend_mvc\branches\INT-81_RD\ng-app\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7                                                              
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (c:\xampp\htdocs\yii\application\test_backend_mvc\branches\INT-81_RD\ng-app\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:203:28)                                               
    at Zone.run (c:\xampp\htdocs\yii\application\test_backend_mvc\branches\INT-81_RD\ng-app\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone-node.js:96:43)                                                           
[16:41:24] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```